# Can I use MS Visual Studio 2013 Community Edition for Excel Add-in development

Tags: visual-studio, excel-addins

I am considering creating a simple ribbon tab with a few options that would significantly increase my productivity at work. 
As far as I see from MSDN, I can only do this by using MS Visual Studio, but I don't really want to purchase one (though I am keen to share the code as an open source project).

Do you know if I can do this using Community Edition of the software or I need a Professional edition at least?

Comment: You could simply download and try it?!?

Comment: Not an easy stuff to do at a corporate laptop... I personally use Mac. So, unfortunately, not an option

Comment: The capabilities of Community are the same as Professional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer is Yes, i.e  you can do this using Community edition of Visual Studio.

Comment: Yes, provided you install the Office Developer Tools as well!